# PHP Laravel - How to use Spatie Async for concurrent functions

Tags: php, asynchronous

I'm trying to run some functions in parallel with [spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async) and having some trouble. I designed this quick test:

Should take 37s and output 1 2 3 4

```
sleep(20); echo "<br> 1";
sleep(5); echo "<br> 2";
sleep(10); echo "<br> 3";
sleep(2); echo "<br> 4";
```

Then using spatie, this should take 20s and return 4 2 3 1
**But it is still taking 37s and returning 1 2 3 4**

```
$pool = Pool::create();
        
        $pool
            ->add(function () 
            {
                sleep(20); echo "<br> 1";
            })
            ->then(function ($output) {})
            ->catch(function ($exception) {})
            ->timeout(function () {})
        ;
        
        $pool
            ->add(function () 
            {
                sleep(5); echo "<br> 2";
            })
            ->then(function ($output) {})
            ->catch(function ($exception) {})
            ->timeout(function () {})
        ;
        
        $pool->add(function () {
                sleep(10); echo "<br> 3";
            })
            ->then(function ($output) {})
            ->catch(function ($exception) {})
            ->timeout(function () {})
        ;
        
        $pool
            ->add(function () {
                sleep(2); echo "<br> 4";
            })
            ->then(function ($output) {})
            ->catch(function ($exception) {})
            ->timeout(function () {})
        ;
        
        await($pool);
```

Comment: Does it take 20s? It might just be merging the standard output of each process at the end instead of echoing instantly

Comment: @apokryfos - nope still 37s

Comment: Do a var_dump of `Pool::isSupported()` to check whether you can run async operations to begin with

Comment: There's also [`pthreads`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php) and [`parallel`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php) ...which actually do work, while being able to program at a lower level. `spatie` might depend on certain modules, because what you describe there is the behavior of a single one thread, time-sliced.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation,

> If the required extensions (pcntl and posix) are not installed in your current PHP runtime, the Pool will automatically fallback to synchronous execution of tasks.

I highly suspect that this is the case in your environment, so in other words it only runs in the main thread.

But, you also need to remember that **concurrency does not mean parallelism**.

In the case of single thread, it can still achieve concurrency  because it essentially performs switching between tasks. But, at a given time there can only be **one** task that is running.

In your example, the `sleep` function essentially **halts** the main thread so it doesn't matter if you run 4 different tasks asynchronously it will still take the total sleep time of all the tasks (37 s) because the main thread needs to wait that long in order for all the tasks to finish.

The same case applies when you run a some operations that is CPU intensive. Running multiple tasks of it in the same thread asynchronously won't give you faster execution because there is only one thread that switches between tasks.